# Kendo DropdownList not properly updating the drop down

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, html-select

I have a kendo dropdownList that contains a list of dates.  After binding has completed, I use the following code to select the most current date.

```
var dates = $("#date").data("kendoDropDownList");
dates.select(dates.dataSource.data().length - 1);
```

Simple enough, and the correct date appears in the dropdown, but when you open the dropdown you can clearly see that the dropdown has the first item selected instead of the last.

The image can be found [here](http://i41.tinypic.com/2s967oi.png)

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/yaK2W/) and it works fine. Does my code work for you? Otherwise, which OS/Browser do you use?

Comment: Did you look at the image that I linked?  Everything appears to be fine and you can see that 201311 is in the text area but when you open the dropdownlist the selected item is 201306, so that date cannot be selected until you actually click on a different date and then select it again.  It occurs in all browsers.  Not sure if it matters but I am using Razor to create the control.

Comment: I looked at the image and yes your image is wrong but when I tried to reproduce it in my Mac with Chrome, Firefox and Safari (the fiddle that I provided the link in my first comment) it worked fine. Did you try my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/yaK2W/)

Comment: Tested also my JSFiddle in Win7Pro with IE9, Firefox and Chrome also works. Please check my code a let me know if this works.

Comment: I think that it may have something to do with how the control is being bound.  I am binding using data that is coming back from a link query, so I have to specify the DataTextField for the control which also may be part of the problem, and I am not setting DataValueField.

Comment: If you post you actual code we might try to help you.

Comment: Your code was good, I missed the fact it wasn't actually executing the javascript that I thought that it was.  I had a post and in the result, it was executing $("#date").data("kendoDropDownList").text(result);  Thanks for the help.  I actually tried creating a bunch of various samples and non of them could reproduce the problem.  I nearly went insane!

Comment: How do you mark as answered?

Comment: Since the were comments you cannot :-) Maybe we can ask for closing it since it was not an actual problem so probably will not help others.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a binding issue I was getting a variable result from the server and if that result is not null then set the value with the result otherwise do the select if it is null.